# Why is the positive energy theorem relevant if assumes the weak energy condition?

Tags: general-relativity, energy

The positive energy theorem states that the gravitational energy of an isolated system is nonnegative, and can only be zero when the system has no gravitating objects. But it assumes that the dominant energy condition holds, which assumes that the weak energy condition holds, by which the matter density observed by the corresponding observers is always non-negative.

What is the relevance of the positive energy theorem then?

Comment: I'm not at all versed in GR in any detail, but that sounds pretty relevant right off the bat. It sounds like it's saying that the gravitational binding energy of a system of masses (the only way you would have negative energies, at least from a newtonian standpoint) can never exceed the rest energy of those masses. This is quite plausible to me, but nontrivial, hence the need for a theorem. (But take my opinion with a big grain of salt until an expert weighs in.)

Comment: But doesnt the weak energy condition already assume that negative energies cannot be measured?